# Undefined local variable or method 'product'

Tags: ruby

I am doing a task that requires me add some products together and give a 10% discount providing the total is above £60. I have done the following:

```
class Checkout
  def initialize (rules)
    @rules = rules
    @cart = []
  end

  def scan (item)
    if product == Product.find(item)
      @cart << product.clone
      #Clone preserves frozen state whereas .dup() doesn't if use would raise a
      #NoMethodError
    end
  end

  def total
    @cart = @rules.apply @cart

  end

def self.find item
  [item]
end

co = Checkout.new(Promotional_Rules.new)

co.empty_cart
co.scan(1)
co.scan(2)
co.scan(3)
puts "Total price: #{co.total}"
puts

co.empty_cart
co.scan(1)
co.scan(3)
co.scan(1)
puts "Total price: #{co.total}"
puts

co.empty_cart
co.scan(1)
co.scan(2)
co.scan(1)
co.scan(3)
puts "Total price: #{co.total}"
puts
```

However when I run this in `irb` I get undefined variable or method product. Sounds a bit daft but this should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using one too many equal signs

```
  def scan (item)
    # if product == Product.find(item) 
    if product = Product.find(item) # <--- should be this
      @cart << product.clone
      #Clone preserves frozen state whereas .dup() doesn't if use would raise a
      #NoMethodError
    end
  end
```

Of course, then you'll get a different error since `find` doesn't exist on `Product` yet... which I think you're trying to define here:

```
def self.find item # self should be changed to Product
  [item]
end
```

Then you're going to get an error for `apply` not existing for `Promotional_Rules` ...

---

One of the best ways to debug these errors is follow the stack traces. So for the last error I get the following message:

```
test.rb:53:in `total': undefined method `apply' for #<Promotional_Rules:0x007f94f48bc7a8> (NoMethodError)
    from test.rb:72:in `<main>'
```

That's basically saying that at `line 53` you'll find `apply` hasn't been defined for `@rules` which is an instance of `Promotional_Rules`. Looking at the `Promotional_Rules` class you've clearly defined that method as `apply_to_item` and not `apply`. If you keep following and fixing the rabbit trails like this for stack traces you'll be able to debug your program with ease!

Comment: @user532339 if you remember to come back in 10 minutes you'll be my most favoritest user532339 ever!

Comment: Though now I am getting a `undefined method 'find'` in the scan method :/